# How do I create an custom design time property editor for a behavior in Blend 4?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, behavior, blend

I'm trying to create an property editor for a custom bevaior in Microsoft Expression Blend 4. Since there is almost no docs covering this, I need some guidance! Is there anyone here that has accomplished this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  are you trying to create an editor for a specific property type or for the behavior overall?

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Silverlight Analytics Framework has many examples of this for WPF, Silverlight and Windows Phone 7:  http://msaf.codeplex.com.  The framework is open source so you can see how the behaviors have design-time assemblies in Blend.  [This article](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/11/17/silverlight-design-time-extensibility.aspx) is probably the best resource on creating design-time assemblies.

Comment: Thanks for this Michael, those are both great resources! I won't make this the answer yet, since I'm not been able to solve my problem though.